# Selecting one checkbox shall unselect others

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, input

I'm working with a form where I have enclosed Input tags in divs styled as Cards. Currently, the user can select multiple options by clicking on the card. What I want to implement is that the user shall only be able to select a single card. If he selects some other card, the already selected card shall become unselected. How can I achieve this?

Clicking on the card adds the class **module-inactive** to the div which makes it look unselected by reducing its opacity.

Here is my HTML Code:

```
<div id="heat-one" class="module d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <input type="checkbox" class="module-check" id="card1">
    <p>Comb. Heat and Power</p>
</div>
<div class="add module module-inactive d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <input type="checkbox" class="module-check" id="card2">
    <p>Heat Pump</p>
</div>
<div class="add module module-inactive d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <input type="checkbox" class="module-check" id="card3">
    <p>Natural Gas Heating</p>
</div>
<div class="add module module-inactive d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <input type="checkbox" class="module-check" id="card4">
    <p>Wood Heating System</p>
</div>
```

Following is the JavaScript that is currently implemented:

```
const checkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll(".module-check");
        checkBoxes.forEach((checkBox) =>
        checkBox.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
            if (checkBox.checked) {
            e.target.parentElement.classList.remove("module-inactive");
            } else {
            e.target.parentElement.classList.add("module-inactive");
            }
        })
        );
```

I hope I can explain my problem.

Comment: Add `name="whateverYouWantAsLongAsItIsIdenticalForEachCheckbox"` to each input.

Comment: @zer00ne that isn't right, unless you change the checkboxes (`type="checkbox"`) to radio buttons (`type="radio"`). In which case, yes they should have the same `name` attribute - and that's exactly what should be done, as checkboxes are for individual yes/no options which can be chosen independently, whereas radio buttons are for choosing one from a short list of options.

Comment: Duh, just woke up  exactly @RobinZigmond, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use radio boxes, as they are mutually exclusive.

Change all your current checkboxes to:

```
<input type="radio" class="module-check" id="card1" value="card1" name="whatever">
```

You don't need any JavaScript for this feature to work the way you expect.

Comment: Thank you for this, makes much sense now. But how do I toggle class of the parent div now based on which radio element is selected?

Comment: True, you need to use JavaScript then. Your original JS code should work the same.

Comment: @Ghazi360 You may want to consider the `has()` pseudo-code. It's just not supported by Firefox yet, but you wouldn't need any Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is the functionality of a [`<input type="radio">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio) element (or more input elements with the same name). You can style the "cards" using the [:checked pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) of the radio button.

And you can use the [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) for "mapping" a click on the text to the radio button.

The value attribute on each input element can be used for deciding wish item is selects.

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: .5em;
}

input[type='radio'] {
  display: none;
}

input[type='radio']:checked + p {
  opacity: 1;
}

label p {
  border: thin solid black;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label id="heat-one" class="module d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <input type="radio" name="group1" value="1" class="module-check" id="card1">
    <p>Comb. Heat and Power</p>
  </label>
  <label class="add module module-inactive d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <input type="radio" name="group1" value="2" class="module-check" id="card2">
    <p>Heat Pump</p>
  </label>
  <label class="add module module-inactive d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <input type="radio" name="group1" value="3" class="module-check" id="card3">
    <p>Natural Gas Heating</p>
  </label>
  <label class="add module module-inactive d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <input type="radio" name="group1" value="4" class="module-check" id="card4">
    <p>Wood Heating System</p>
  </label>
</form>
```